# Asymmetrical [JsonInclude] behaviours for Serialization from Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a class with a field, whose type is `List<String>`.
I want to ignore empty list when serializaton so the field does not show in my json. But when deserializaton, I want it empty list will be included in my java object.
`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` will ignore it for both cases. should I write a custom serializDifferenter? What is the best approach for that?

Comment: i think you should go for custom serializer

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just initialize the `List<String>` to an empty `ArrayList<String>` in the Java object, just this way:

```
public class JsonTestObject implements Serializable {

    private String propertyOne = null;

    private Integer intProperty = 0;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

The serialization with an empty List will produce this kind of json:

```
{"propertyOne":"aaaaa","intProperty":1000}
```

And with a sinple deserialization ot this json sample, the `List<String>` will be initialized to an empty list